# Trying to launch an external url via callback passed into a custom widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a small widget for a website button.

```
class WebsiteButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String url;
  final Future<void> launchCallback;

  WebsiteButton(this.url, this.launchCallback);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (url != null && url.isNotEmpty) {
      return IconButton(
        icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.globe),
        tooltip: url,
        onPressed: () => launchCallback,
      );
    } else {
      return IconButton(
        icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.globe),
        onPressed: null,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

To make it more reusable (e.g. in case I wanna set different logic of launching url in a webview instead of browser) I'm trying to pass the callback `_launch` into the widget like this:

```
    Future<void> _launch(String url) async {
      if (await canLaunch(url)) {
        await launch(
          url,
          forceSafariVC: false,
          forceWebView: false,
        );
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $url';
      }
    }
    ...
    WebsiteButton(
      profile.website,
      _launch(profile.website)
    ),
```

It results in a strange behaviour: the url launches as soon as the page containing the widget is built, not as the `IconButton` is clicked as I expected. What am I missing?

*(Flutter master v1.12.16-pre.35, url_launcher: 5.2.7)*

Comment: Instead of onPressed: () => launchCallback, either say onPressed: launchCallback, or onPressed: () => launchCallback(), don't think that would cause the issue you are describing but it would prevent the callback from executing when you press the button

Comment: I'm guessing you are calling the callback when you pass it to the WebsiteButton. You can use the method name without parentheses as a variable, e.g. passing it as a parameter, but when you want it to execute use the parentheses

Comment: Or onPressed: () async => launchCallback(),

Comment: @kris but how to pass the callback without executing it when it has a parameter (url in this case)? It says `error: The argument type 'Future<void> Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<void>'.` if i pass it just as `_launch`

Comment: Oh I see now. Pass it in as () => _launch(url)

Comment: Awesome! Sorry just did, or you can post your own, either way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the method that you are passing to the widget as a parameter is being called when you pass it. If you make the changes the other comment suggests, and also use an anonymous function that calls the _launch method with the url string as the parameter for the widget.

So, it would look like this:

```
WebsiteButton(
    profile.website,
    () => _launch(profile.website)
)
```

Or you could pass the url and the _launch method to the WebsiteButton, and then call _launch with the url inside WebsiteButton.

Comment: What's the best practice of defining a type of `launchCallback` in `WebsiteButton` then? Is it ok without a type or rather `VoidCallback` or `AsyncCallback`?

Comment: I think it is whatever you find easiest to read. Since typing is optional it is really just to make it easier for you or someone else to maintain or reuse the code. I might say Function as a type but Future<void> I think is pretty standard also